# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos ax)^{b/x^2}$ with Hôpital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was hoping someone could help me check my work here.  $\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos ax)^{b/x^2}$ takes the form $1^\infty$, so if we take the natural logarithm, we find that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \log (\cos ax)^{b/x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{b \log( \cos ax )}{x^2}=\frac{0}{0}$$
so we can apply Hôpital's Rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{d}{dx} b \log( \cos ax )}{\frac{d}{dx}x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ -ab \tan ax }{2x}=\frac{0}{0}$$
so we need to apply the rule again
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} -ab \tan ax }{\frac{d}{dx}2x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ -a^2b \sec^2ax }{2}=-\frac{a^2b}{2}$$

$$\implies \lim_{x \to 0}(\cos ax)^{b/x^2} = e^{-\frac{a^2b}{2}}$$

Comment: Everything looks good .

Comment: Yeah it's correct.

Comment: If L'Hospital is not mandatory, we can use $$\cos bx=(1-\sin^2bx)^{1/2}$$ like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437846/evaluate-lim-x-to-0-left-frac1-cos-x-sin-xx3-right/3437905#3437905

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks OK, although the writing can be improved. I will follow your thoughts and rewrite the answer slightly as follows.

First of all, I assume in your original problem $a>0$ (and $b\neq 0$) and thus near $x=0$, $\cos(ax)>0$. So
$$
\log\big[(\cos ax)^{b/x^2}\big]=\frac{b}{x^2}\log(\cos ax),\quad x\neq 0.
$$
By L'Hopital rule, 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\cos ax)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-a\tan(ax)}{2x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-a^2\sec^2(ax)}{2}=\frac{-a^2}{2}.
$$
Thus, the continuity of the exponential function implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}(\cos ax)^{b/x^2}=\exp\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\log\big[(\cos ax)^{b/x^2}\big]\right)=\exp\left(\frac{-a^2b}{2}\right)
$$

---

Note: the expression "$\frac{0}{0}$" is used for denoting one of the [indeterminate forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). It is not a "legal" mathematical notation and should *not* be used in formal writing. For instance, it does not make sense to write $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{0}{0}$, although one could say that this is a $\frac{0}{0}$ type limit.

Comment: You're right I wrote 0/0 to show that it is a form that shows we can use Hôpital's rule. Thanks for the reminder. I've been doing that in my notes to make sure I show we can use the rule.